# Show the result of jQuery calculation to a form

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working on a project. I have some options, and the price will be shown after the user choose the option. My codes are simply written below

**HTML**

```
<select name="package" id="package" onchange="pricingOption()">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select> <br />
<label for="price">Price : </label>
<input type="text" id="price" disabled="disabled" value="$ <?php echo $price ?>">
```

I intentionally set the `<input type="text">` as disabled to prevent the user from typing the price :)
The PHP code is used for sending the value to database (MariaDB).

**jQuery**

```
function pricingOption(){
  chosen=document.getElementById("package").value;
  price=document.getElementById("price");
  if(chosen=="A"){
    price+=30;
  }
  else if(chosen=="B"){
    price+=20;
  }
  else if(chosen=="C"){
    price+=10;
  }
}
```

My problems are :

1. The price couldn't show in the `<input type="text">` although I have changed the option
2. In the `<input type="text">`, it shows

> **Notice**: Undefined variable: price in **C:\xampp\datalocation\file.php** on line **7**

So, I write

```
<?php $price="" ?>
```

So in database, the price is 0 (after I send it to database)

How to fix this? Any idea?

(Please pay attention to my PHP and jQuery, I have no problem with MySQL. I think if my PHP and jQuery are going well, the query for MySQL will not be a problem)

Comment: your jquery is pure javascript

Comment: please provide both PHP code and jQuery code which you have right now,  seems you are hiding main part.

Comment: More over your javascript do not even setting any values for PHP variable or input,  and for seeing change happened in PHP variable you either need to refresh but then changes will be gone,  or you need to call AJAX and set values in to input box

Comment: 1.initially you have to set a value in $price variable.    2.Your value attribute of hidden   should look like -- value=" <?php echo $price ?>"--- remove $ sign .   3rd. In your javascript price veriable is storing object it should store value like  --price = document.getElementById("checkyear").value; --.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Im not sure what you want you js code to do. This is what i guess:
The `+=` confuses me. Do you want to add or append the numbers?

```js
function pricingOption(){
  chosen = $("#package").val();
  price = parseInt($("#price").val());
  
  if(chosen=="A"){
    price+=30;
  }
  else if(chosen=="B"){
    price+=20;
  }
  else if(chosen=="C"){
    price+=10;
  }
  
  $('#price_display').text( "Price: " + price );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="package" id="package" onchange="pricingOption()">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select> <br />
<label for="price" id="price_display">Price: </label>

<!-- filled by php -->
<input type="text" id="price" disabled="disabled" value="100">
```

To fix:

> **Notice**: Undefined variable: price in **C:\xampp\datalocation\file.php** on line **7**

You need to assign `$price` before you echo it. Please provide you php code.

**Extra**

[Event-Listener in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (thx @Dipesh Parmar):

```
$('#package').('input', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: your code do not show proper use of jQuery either.  why in a world you call function on change,  jQuery already have event listener to do it.  And you are even asking question to OP in answer block :)

Comment: Sure, i could rewrite the whole code, but apparently the question is asked by a beginner and i like to pick em up where he or she is.

Comment: It works for me :) Yas, I'm a beginner so I gotta find some sources to help me and I got this (calling function onchange). I didn't write PHP code a lot, I have written all the PHP code which are related to pricing option. Other than that, just instruction to put all the value to database. I think for assign `$price`, I'll remove it and change it with another idea. I think that's all enough :)